# Amazon Service to submit CPU intensive task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a web application running 24/7 in a AWS micro instance and it works just fine.

Occasionally (10 to 50 times a day) I need process big amounts of data (stored on RDS) in a CPU intensive task. That's overkill for my micro instance.

Starting a EC2 server for this tasks doesn't seem a good idea because these tasks must be executed on demand when a user asks for them, and I need low latency (less than 10 seconds).

Is there any amazon service where I can submit my task and take advantage of higher CPU capacity?

Keep in mind that my task needs to read a big amount of data from RDS.

Answer (score 0):

You can queue up all those task 10 to 50 over a particular cut-off time during a day and launch an instance to process that and terminate the same when you are done with the processing. The scheduling part of that can be done by the Micro instance.

Once the Micro instance starts the High Compute Instance; then rest of that can be carried out by High Compute Instance; once the queue for all those to be processed are empty you can terminate that instance.

This is like 0 Instance to 1 Instance over a schedule.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry I didn't made explicit that these task must be done on demand when a users asks for them, that's why I need low latency.

Comment: If it is on demand, it better you setup a auto-scaling setup to do the CPU Intensive task, you can start with single small instance and scale out if you need more power; you can come back to single instance if you don't have load

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cost that you are willing to pay, the complexity of the processing, the future scale of your service, the ability to pre-calculate your results and so on.

One option is to have a larger instance (or pool of instances in case of scale of your service), ready for processing that you can trigger them. You can lower the cost of this machine by using reserve instances pricing (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/), or even better, using Spot instances (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/). With spot you are facing the risk that some of the times, you won't be able to have the instances up and running, and you need to back it with on-demand instance(s).

This is probably a more expensive solution, but as you have more and more jobs like that running, the "cost per job" is decreasing dramatically.

Another option is to off-load the processing to a different service. If you can run your calculation with a query syntax of external services like DynamoDB or Redis, for example, you can keep on using your micro instance to trigger the query. For example, Redis with ElastiCache can have complex data manipulations like sorted set intersection etc. You do need to make sure that you have your data also in the other data store, and write the query.

Another option is to have these calculations pre-calculated. It really depends on the type of jobs you need to run. If you can prepare these output in advanced and only update their results with the latest data from the time it was calculated to the time it is requested, it might also be easier on your machines to prepare for it without these unpredictable CPU peaks.

Comment: I don't think keeping instances for a few tasks is cost effective and I already discarded starting instances on demand. That's why I'm looking for a service where I can submit tasks. I thought Data Pipeline could be the way to go, but I'm not sure if it is a good fit, specially if it will initiate my task immediately.

Comment: Data Pipeline can either use existing resources (instances or clusters already running) or start them for you. It is not providing ready made resources outside your instances.

Comment: That's good to know. I guess I won't find what I'm looking for between Amazon services, it's all about EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

We used AWS Batch for this, basically because it heads above other options out there. Besides AWS Batch, we considered additional servers, AWS Lambda, using a separate server for each task and so on.

But we finally chose AWS Batch because of the number of reasons:

1. In AWS Batch, all processes are completely isolated. This means, that the tasks will not impact each other & break the workflow.
2. You can set the min. and max. RAM you want to use up
3. AWS Batch supports containers which makes it easier to integrate if you use containers already
4. You can also create queues for different tasks to gain more control over your resources and expenses.
5. AWS Batch is very price-effective, meaning you pay for what you use.

It's also pretty easy to set up. Here's a quick code snippet on how to launch rockets for each individual user. For more info go here: https://fulcrum.rocks/blog/cpu-intensive-tasks

```
`const comand = "npm run rocket"
const newJob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    batch.submitJob(
        {
            jobName: "your_important_job",
            jobDefinition: "killer_process",
            jobQueue: "night_users",
            timeout: {
                attemptDurationSeconds: 600
            },
            retryStrategy: {
                attempts: 1
            },
            containerOverrides: {
                vcpus: 2,
                memory: 2048,
                command: [comand]
            }
        },
        (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(data);
        }
    );
});
`
```

Comment: In mid '14 when this question was originally asked, Lambda hadn't been launched yet. I think that for my use case Lambda would have been the perfect solution. Thank you for introducing AWS Batch, I wasn't aware of its existence and it seems to be a really flexible alternative to Lambda.

Comment: Oh, right. Didn't notice this was back in '14. 

Yes, AWS Batch is really convenient and we prefer it over Lambda. However, I can't deny that Lambda is also an excellent solution, which works perfectly for smaller tasks.